# Node.js Child-Process spawn giving ENOENT error when cwd option is used

Tags: node.js

Can you please let me know why the below code is failing with ENOENT .
The path to the exe is present.
If I run the code by keeping the exe on the current folder and remove cwd option it works fine.

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;


const child = spawn('child_process_test.exe',['test','test2','test3'],{ cwd:'C:\Users\xxx\workspace\xxxNodeJsTest\Test\DLLs' });

child.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.log('child process exited with code : ' , code);
});


child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log('stdout: ' , data.toString());
});

child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log('stderr: ' , data.toString());
});

child.on('error',(err) => {
    console.log('Error: ' , err.toString());
});
```

The error i get is

Error : Error: spawn child_process_test.exe ENOENT

Comment: How do you run program?
What is `process.cwd()` shows?
Did you try to pass absolute path ?

Comment: I run it from command line like this > node child_process_test

Comment: process.cwd() is showing the parent folder path (i.e the path when I am running the node program from

Comment: can you please explain what you mean by pass absolute path ?

Comment: `C:\Users\xxx\workspace\xxxNodeJsTest\Test\DLLs\child_process_test.exe`

Comment: thank you this actually worked ! had to use \\ instead of \                       
 const child = spawn('C:\\Users\\xxx\\workspace\\xxxNodeJsTest\\Test\\DLLs\\child_process_test.exe',['test','test2','test3']);

Comment: I understanded the problem - `cwd` in `spawn` options not the place where application looking for executable file to run it. It is current working directory for executable that could be differ from directory where executable placed.